# Javascript Object access; Outputs fine, selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, spotify

so I have this Object, which when I console.log it and look at it in the inspector looks just fine.
[Object in Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz4YJ.png)

But when I print out the keys of the object, I only get this as a result:
[Object Keys in Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iprc5.png)

And everything I print out after that (object.value) looks something like this:

`ƒ (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){r.each(b,function(b,c){r.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==r.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i()),this}`

How can I access just the "responseJSON" from the first screenshot?

Some Background information that might be important:
I got the object from the spotify web-api, authorization etc. works all just fine.

```
function getUserData(accessToken) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try 'object.responseText'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are enumerating a jQuery deferred object properties. Deferred objects are asynchronous, in your case coming from an HTTP request.

To properly enumerate over your object you should first wait for it to be available using `Deferred.then`. Replace your code from :

```
console.log(Object.keys(your_object))
```

to :

```
your_object.then(function(result) {
    console.log(Object.keys(result))
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err)
})
```